# discord.js - command is adding more fields to embed

Tags: javascript, discord, embed

When i do !commands, it makes an embed with the 5 fields i gave it when i do it again, it adds the 5 fields to the next embed making it 10, then 15, then 20. How do i stop this?

```
const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
        if (message.content === "!commands") {
            cmdEmbed
                .setTitle("Bot Commands")
                .setColor(0xff0000)
                .addField("!website", "Brings up the official website")
                .addField("!botinfo", "See who helped and made the bot.")
                .addField("!schedule", "Brings up the Schedule")
                .addField("!calendar", "Brings up the Calendar")
                .addField("!whitecalendar", "Brings up the White calendar ")
                .setFooter("Commands");
    
            message.channel.send(Embed); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "!commands") {
        const Embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Bot Commands")
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .addField("!website", "Brings up the official website")
            .addField("!botinfo", "See who helped and made the bot.")
            .addField("!schedule", "Brings up the Schedule")
            .addField("!calendar", "Brings up the Calendar")
            .addField("!whitecalendar", "Brings up the White calendar ")
            .setFooter("Commands");
        message.channel.send(Embed); 
    }
});
```

It's because you defined embed, the redefined it again with the next command, then so on and so forth. Try the code above.